# Guice Jersey slf4j - request id logging

Tags: jersey, slf4j

In all of my requests, there is a header (request id) that I want to log, in case of anything - on any log level.

Is there a way to inject this into the sl4fj logging? So that the logger always tried to log the request id, in for example logging an exception, but the request.

Or do I always need to add this as a parameter to the logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really related to Guice.

You have in slf4j a concept of MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context). You can put variables in an MDC. These variables are local to the thread and are added to each log generated by this thread. The typical use case of an MDC is to add in every log the user associated with an HTTP request, or a session-id (ie, your use case).

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

For a short example, you put a variable in MDC like this:

```
MDC.put("userId", currentUser);
```

and you can add in an appender format the variable with:

```
%X{userId}
```

Theoretically, it could be possible to implement this feature with Guice by injecting a request-scoped logger, but it's really more costly and less integrated with the logging framework. I didn't advise you to do this kind of things!

Comment: Thanks. MDC is the proper way to go. However my project is (and "must") using JUL. If I manage to get slf4j + logback this is the proper way to handle this and therefor I accept your answer!

Comment: It worked very well! I didn't inject a request-scoped-logger but I've created a request scoped bean that, on post construct, register itself in MDC. Thank you!